# arff file error - java.io.IOException: end of line expected, read Token(Inequality), line 3)

Tags: java, weka, ioexception, arff

I created a ARFF file but when I try to upload it into WEKA I get the following message:

> java.io.IOException: end of line expected, read Token(Inequality), line 3

I searched online but I cannot manage to find any solutions for my problem.

Below is part of my ARFF file.

ARFF file for GII index prediction

> @relation Gender Inequality Index
>   @attribute GII Value numeric
>   @attribute Maternal mortality rate numeric
>   @attribute Adolescent fertility rate numeric
>   @attribute Seats in parliament numeric
>   @attribute Female population with at least secondary education numeric
>   @attribute Male population with at least secondary education numeric
>   @attribute Female labour force participation numeric
>   @attribute Male labour force participation numeric
>   @data

187 instances

```
0.065, 7, 7.4, 39.6, 95.6, 94.7, 61.7, 70.1
0.115, 7, 12.5, 29.2, 92.2, 92.2, 58.8, 72.3
0.256, 21, 27.4, 17.0, 94.7, 94.3, 57.5, 70.1
```

Comment: Weka is crashing because of line 3. You should show us how you tried to load it.

Answer (score -3):

There is an tool for conversion of the exel data into the .arff file ,you should follow this for without any error we can upload to weka

Comment: This is not constructive feedback.